# pygame rect doesn't change position while i give it a new position and update it

Tags: python, pygame

okay so i'm fairly new to programming and i'm making a game based on the arcade game alien invasion. but i want to make an intro with moving text to show credits at the start because it's fun and good practice to learn. but i cant seem to make it work. i want the text to fly from the side of the screen to middle stop there then fly away again

so here is the function that draws the texts.

```
from Settings import *
import sys

class TextsObjects:
def __init__(self):
    self.setting = Settings()
    self.intro_settings = IntroSettings()

    self.display_intro_1 = DisplayText(
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_1,
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_1_pos_x,
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_1_pos_y,
        self.intro_settings.font_size,
        self.setting.light_grey
        )

    self.display_intro_2 = DisplayText(
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_2,
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_2_pos_x,
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_2_pos_y,
        self.intro_settings.font_size,
        self.setting.light_grey
        )

    self.display_intro_title = DisplayText(
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_title,
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_title_pos_x,
        self.intro_settings.intro_text_title_pos_y,
        self.intro_settings.font_size,
        self.setting.light_grey)


class Intro:
    def __init__(self, screen, setting):
        self.screen = screen
        self.setting = setting
        self.i_setting = IntroSettings()
        self.intro_text = TextsObjects()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.speed = 50 * setting.time
        self.screen_c_left = setting.screen_width / 2 - self.speed / 2
        self.screen_c_right = setting.screen_width / 2 + self.speed / 2

    def intro_update(self):
        # reset the background so you don't get multiple drawings onscreen
        self.screen.fill(self.setting.dark_blueish)

        if 0 <= self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x <= \
                self.setting.screen_width:

            # Draw the first text
            self.intro_text.display_intro_1.draw_me_with_shadow(
                    self.screen)

        if self.screen_c_left < self.i_setting.intro_text_2_pos_x < \
                self.screen_c_right:

            # Draw the second text
            self.intro_text.display_intro_2.draw_me_with_shadow(
                self.screen)

        pygame.display.update()

    def show_intro(self):
        self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x += self.speed
        # show the intro for self.intro_time amount of time
        for frames in range(0, self.setting.fps * 3):
            # test for events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                print(event)
                # when the window is closed stop the game loop
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.intro_update()
            self.setting.clock.tick(self.setting.fps)
```

and here are the classes that are relevant:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):

        # screen size
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 500

        # set clock and fps
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 60
        # calculate the seconds in every frame
        self.time = 1 / self.fps

    class IntroSettings:
        def __init__(self):
            self.setting = Settings()
            self.font_size = 100
            self.timer_font_size = 10

            self.intro_text_1_pos_x = (self.setting.screen_width / 2) - 100
            self.intro_text_1_pos_y = \
                (self.setting.screen_height / 2 - self.font_size)
            self.intro_text_1 = "A game by:"

            self.intro_text_2_pos_x = (self.setting.screen_width / 2)
            self.intro_text_2_pos_y = \
                (self.setting.screen_height / 2 + self.font_size)
            self.intro_text_2 = "Mark Olieman"

            self.intro_text_title_pos_x = (self.setting.screen_width / 2)
            self.intro_text_title_pos_y = (self.setting.screen_height + self.font_size)
            self.intro_text_title = "Alien Invasion!"

            self.intro_text_timer_pos_x = 20
            self.intro_text_timer_pos_y = 20

            self.speed = -2


    class DisplayText:
        def __init__(self, text, pos_x, pos_y, font_size, text_color):

            self.font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", font_size)

            self.text_surf = self.font.render(text, True, text_color)
            self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect()
            self.text_rect.center = (pos_x, pos_y)

            self.shadow_color = (0, 0, 0)

            self.text_surf_shadow = self.font.render(text, True, self.shadow_color)
            self.text_rect_shadow = self.text_surf.get_rect()
            self.text_rect_shadow.center = (pos_x + 10, pos_y + 5)

        def draw_me(self, screen):
            screen.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)

        def draw_me_with_shadow(self, screen):
            screen.blit(self.text_surf_shadow, self.text_rect_shadow)
            screen.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
```

i am sorry for the amount of code but because i don't know where the problem lies i want you guys to have all the relevant information so at last here is my main game loop

```
import pygame
from Settings import *
from Entities import *
from Game_functions import *
from Menu import *

# make the modules available
setting = Settings()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((setting.screen_width, setting.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion, By Mark Olieman")

intro = Intro(screen, setting)
player = Player(screen, setting)
bullet = Bullet(screen, setting, player)
intro_set = IntroSettings()

# initizialize pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

# initizialize the screen and set a caption


# function to start gaming
def gaming():
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    intro.show_intro()
    intro_set.intro_text_1_pos_x += intro.speed
    print(intro_set.intro_text_1_pos_x)
    # Game Loop
    while True:
        # check events and make actions happen
        events(bullets, player, screen, setting)

        # update everything and draw bullets
        update(player, setting, bullets, screen)

        # update screen at certain fps
        pygame.display.update()
        setting.clock.tick(setting.fps)


# Start the game
gaming()

# Stop the game
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You probably want to rewrite all your imports. That many `*` imports is bound to overwrite something.

Comment: oh okay how do you recommend i write it? because many things i write become quite long if i have to put Settings. before it

Comment: example `import Settings  as st` then for anything that uses that import you do `st.method()`. This will prevent over writing of methods that have the same names from different imports. May not be your problem here but good practice anyway.

Comment: if something doesn't work then you can start with `print()` to display values in variables in different moment and to see which part of code is executed. OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: i did use print everywhere i could and i don't get an error because the program works just not how i want it to

Comment: program doesn't have to get error but it can calculate different values then you expect and it can run different functions then you can expect. If some values have wrong values then it may run different `if/else` then you expect - using ie. `print("I'm in `else`")` you can see which part of code is executed.  You should use `print()` in functions which update data (before and afrer update) and draw it. You can compare if in both function you have the same expected values. So use `print()` everywhere to see values everywhere - it helps to see how code works.

Comment: BTW: we can't run your code because it is incomplete and we can't see what is a problem - so you have to on your own test all values in all places.

Comment: you are completely right that is the best way to find an error or fault in your code. but as i have previously mentioned i tried that and it didn't work. the if loop worked and the right values were returned the image just did move on the screen. so that's why i came here for help

Comment: you are right i did not provide you with a working example so i took the liberty to upload all the code to github: https://github.com/markolie20/space-invasion.git

Comment: i tried to run your code and I don't see where you move text. It seems you don't change its position so it doesn't move on screen.

Comment: I made some changes and finally it starts moving. You have two mistakes - (1) you add speed before `loop` but you have to do it inside `loop`. (2) you have two variables with position: one in setting which you change, second in DisplayText which is used to display text. SO you change wrong variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208212/discussion-between-mark-olieman-and-furas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two mistakes in `Intro.show_intro()`

1. you add speed before loop but you have to do it inside loop
2. you add speed to `self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x` but you have to add

   ```
   self.intro_text.display_intro_1.text_rect.x += self.speed
   self.intro_text.display_intro_1.text_rect_shadow.x += self.speed
   ```

---

Correct version which moves text (and shadow) "A game by:"

```
def show_intro(self):

    #self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x += self.speed

    # show the intro for self.intro_time amount of time
    for frames in range(0, self.setting.fps * 3):
        # test for events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            # when the window is closed stop the game loop
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # you have to add speed inside loop
        #self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x += self.speed
        self.intro_text.display_intro_1.text_rect.x += self.speed
        self.intro_text.display_intro_1.text_rect_shadow.x += self.speed

        self.intro_update()
        self.setting.clock.tick(self.setting.fps)
```

---

There can be another problem - `rect.x` can keep only integer values but `speed` has value `0.83` so when you add `0.83` then it can be rounded to `1` so it may move faster then you expect - or it can move too far (or may move not so smooth as you expected). If speed will be smaller then 0.5 then it may even round it to `0` so it will not move.

You may have to keep position in separated values as float values, change them and copy to `rect.x` only before drawing.

---

Full code which I run in one file - I removed some `imports` and elements which I hadn't (ie, `Player`)

```
import sys

class TextsObjects:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setting = Settings()
        self.intro_settings = IntroSettings()

        self.display_intro_1 = DisplayText(
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_1,
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_1_pos_x,
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_1_pos_y,
            self.intro_settings.font_size,
            self.setting.light_grey
            )

        self.display_intro_2 = DisplayText(
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_2,
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_2_pos_x,
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_2_pos_y,
            self.intro_settings.font_size,
            self.setting.light_grey
            )

        self.display_intro_title = DisplayText(
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_title,
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_title_pos_x,
            self.intro_settings.intro_text_title_pos_y,
            self.intro_settings.font_size,
            self.setting.light_grey)


class Intro:
    def __init__(self, screen, setting):
        self.screen = screen
        self.setting = setting
        self.i_setting = IntroSettings()
        self.intro_text = TextsObjects()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.speed = 150 * setting.time
        print(self.speed)
        self.screen_c_left = setting.screen_width / 2 - self.speed / 2
        self.screen_c_right = setting.screen_width / 2 + self.speed / 2

    def intro_update(self):
        # reset the background so you don't get multiple drawings onscreen
        self.screen.fill(self.setting.dark_blueish)

        if 0 <= self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x <= self.setting.screen_width:

            # Draw the first text
            self.intro_text.display_intro_1.draw_me_with_shadow(self.screen)

        if self.screen_c_left < self.i_setting.intro_text_2_pos_x < self.screen_c_right:

            # Draw the second text
            self.intro_text.display_intro_2.draw_me_with_shadow(self.screen)

        pygame.display.update()

    def show_intro(self):
        #self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x += self.speed

        # show the intro for self.intro_time amount of time
        for frames in range(0, self.setting.fps * 3):
            # test for events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                print(event)
                # when the window is closed stop the game loop
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            #self.i_setting.intro_text_1_pos_x += self.speed
            self.intro_text.display_intro_1.text_rect.x += self.speed
            self.intro_text.display_intro_1.text_rect_shadow.x += self.speed

            self.intro_update()
            self.setting.clock.tick(self.setting.fps)


class Settings:
    def __init__(self):

        # screen size
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 500

        # set clock and fps
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 60
        # calculate the seconds in every frame
        self.time = 1 / self.fps

        self.light_grey = (128,128,128)
        self.dark_blueish = (0,0,255)

class IntroSettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setting = Settings()
        self.font_size = 100
        self.timer_font_size = 10

        self.intro_text_1_pos_x = (self.setting.screen_width / 2) - 100
        self.intro_text_1_pos_y = \
            (self.setting.screen_height / 2 - self.font_size)
        self.intro_text_1 = "A game by:"

        self.intro_text_2_pos_x = (self.setting.screen_width / 2)
        self.intro_text_2_pos_y = \
            (self.setting.screen_height / 2 + self.font_size)
        self.intro_text_2 = "Mark Olieman"

        self.intro_text_title_pos_x = (self.setting.screen_width / 2)
        self.intro_text_title_pos_y = (self.setting.screen_height + self.font_size)
        self.intro_text_title = "Alien Invasion!"

        self.intro_text_timer_pos_x = 20
        self.intro_text_timer_pos_y = 20

        self.speed = -2


class DisplayText:
    def __init__(self, text, pos_x, pos_y, font_size, text_color):

        self.font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", font_size)

        self.text_surf = self.font.render(text, True, text_color)
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect()
        self.text_rect.center = (pos_x, pos_y)

        self.shadow_color = (0, 0, 0)

        self.text_surf_shadow = self.font.render(text, True, self.shadow_color)
        self.text_rect_shadow = self.text_surf.get_rect()
        self.text_rect_shadow.center = (pos_x + 10, pos_y + 5)

    def draw_me(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)

    def draw_me_with_shadow(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.text_surf_shadow, self.text_rect_shadow)
        screen.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)

import pygame
#from Entities import *
#from Game_functions import *
#from Menu import *

# initizialize pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

# make the modules available
setting = Settings()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((setting.screen_width, setting.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion, By Mark Olieman")

intro = Intro(screen, setting)
#player = Player(screen, setting)
#bullet = Bullet(screen, setting, player)
intro_set = IntroSettings()

# initizialize the screen and set a caption


# function to start gaming
def gaming():
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    intro.show_intro()
    intro_set.intro_text_1_pos_x += intro.speed
    print(intro_set.intro_text_1_pos_x)
    # Game Loop
    while True:
        # check events and make actions happen
        #events(bullets, player, screen, setting)

        # update everything and draw bullets
        #update(player, setting, bullets, screen)

        # update screen at certain fps
        pygame.display.update()
        setting.clock.tick(setting.fps)

# Start the game
gaming()

# Stop the game
pygame.quit()
```